# SQL Server ambiguous query validation

Tags: sql-server

I have just come across a curious SQL Server behaviour.

In my scenario I have a sort of dynamic database, so I need to check the existence of **tables** and **columns** before run queries involving them.

I can't explain why the query

```
IF 0 = 1 -- Check if NotExistingTable exists in my database
BEGIN
    SELECT NotExistingColumn FROM NotExistingTable
END
GO
```

executes correctly, but the query

```
IF 0 = 1 -- Check if NotExistingColumn exists in my ExistingTable
BEGIN
    SELECT NotExistingColumn FROM ExistingTable
END
GO
```

returns **Invalid column name 'NotExistingColumn'**.

In both cases the **IF** block is not executed and contains an invalid query (the first misses a table, the second a column).

Is there any reason why SQL engine checks for syntax erorrs just in one case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using ?

Comment: Are you talking about "existing rows" or "exising columns"?

Comment: @JacodeGroot I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @TomV Yeah, i need to correct. I'm talking about existing columns, my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Deffered name resolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Deferred name resolution **can only be used when you reference nonexistent table** objects. All other objects must exist at the time the stored procedure is created. For example, when you reference an existing table in a stored procedure you **cannot list nonexistent columns for that table**.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can look through the system tables for the existence of a specific table / column name

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%colname%'
AND t.name LIKE '%tablename%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

The query above will pull back all tables / columns with partial match of a columnname and tablename, just change the like % for exact match.